# Create different database for site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Can we create different database for site collection? In sharepoint for one web application we have one sql server database. Now for different different site collection if i want to create different different database than how can i create that?

Answer (score 2):

You have the following two ways:

1. Create a new content database in SP Central Admin. Restrict all other Content databases to their maximum site limit. After that you create your new site collection. Or
2. You can create a new content database and use Move-SPSite Powershell cmdlet for moving existing site collections to various content database. For more information on Move-SPSite check [msdn link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

I hope you are using SharePoint 2010 and above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. A site collection can not be split into different content databases. You can put different site collections into different content databases. If you want to Create SharePoint Site Collection In Its Own DB you can use this [post](http://alpesh.nakars.com/blog/how-to-create-sharepoint-2010-site-collection-in-its-own-db/).

Answer (score 0):

There is UI way. You can create new content data base from SharePoint Central Administration. Read [this blog post](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-sitecollection-specific-content-database.html).

Answer (score -3):

You can use this link http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-sitecollection-specific-content-database.html it may help u

Comment: Links are good for reference, but never good when answering questions. Links may break in the future, and if your answer has nothing more than a link it'll be useless. Please revise your answer.

Comment: I have to do this pro grammatically. How can we do that using code behind from visual studio